# Google Chrome Randomly Downloading itself

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome, internet-explorer

I'm not normally a Chrome user. I use IE11 on a business laptop, running Win7-32bit. Lately, Google Chrome is been downloading itself and changing all my IE shortcuts to use Chrome instead of IE. I will be working on something and a Chrome internet window will pop-up, out of the blue. I then go look at Programs in the control panel, see that Google Chrome was just downloaded. 
What is going on? If anyone can help, I would really appreciate it.

Comment: You did not install Chrome yourself? It could be possible that it was installed during the installation of another program and you did not uncheck or decline that option. Have you installed any Google or other products recently?

Comment: There are some "updates" (crasy as it sounds) that have chrome as one of those optional packages to install. Example, people have reported for years now that adobe flash when automatically updating will have chrome in its installer, and may not show the options to de-select it.  I assume any update that works that way is probably doing a full un-install re-install to accomplish the update of the program and goes through the whole routine of installing all the stuff packaged with it  So dont trust anybody, check your event logs, and install times in programs and features, for who dun it..

Answer (score 0):

Chrome autoupdates itself regularly in the background without user intervention.

It might also be worthwhile resetting chrome settings from settings advanced as you may have chosen an option for chrome to keep itself as the default browser.

Comment: That's true, but it seems like OP did not want Google Chrome installed in the first place.